# Scala, advise on method signature

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm playing with **scala-js** and trying to implement a simple master-details with the MVP pattern.
Initially I had a `ListView` with two mutators : `setEmpty(empty:Boolean)` and `setItemAt(item:Item, row:Int)`

But I wanted to replace them by overloading the assignement operator

```
trait ListView {

  def empty:Boolean
  def empty_=(empty: Boolean)

  def item(row: Int):Item
  // mutator for item at row     
}
```

It works great for `empty` but for `item` I would like to have a method invocation like :

```
val view:ListView = ..
view.items(row) = item
```

My first idea was to return a special class from the method `items(row)` who have the `=` method to change the view. But then I cannot obtains the item at a given row and this class should be implemented by all implementation of the view.

What can be the **Scala** style to change item at a specific row ?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `update` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with an inner `object items` that has `apply` and `update` methods:

```
trait ListView {
  ...
  object items {
    def apply(row: Int): Item = ???
    def update(row: Int, item: Item): Unit = ???
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
val listView: ListView = ???
val item = listView.items(0)
listView.items(0) = someItem
```